# Pass strings to plugin function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I have simple function to show an image:

```
function helloworld() {
    echo '<img src="'.$link.'" alt=".$alt." />';
}
```

I would like to pass strings link and alt to the function something like that:

```
<?php helloworld('link=www.google.com&alt=picture'); ?>
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: this is really a basic PHP question - read up on how to pass argument to PHP functions. Flagged as off-topic

Comment: not really a wordpress question. have you studied the php documentation, for instance: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is meant to parse query strings. furthermore you have to get data into your function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this is more of a basic PHP question, but I can see where you're coming from.  A lot of WordPress functions accept query string formatted parameters like you're trying to do, so it would be a good idea to know exactly *how* they do it.  Shortcode functions are guilty in particular.

First of all, you need to modify your `helloworld()` method to accept arguments.  Then you pass them through a WordPress function that matches them against defaults.  *Then* you'll have access to them elsewhere:

```
function helloworld( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'link' => 'www.google.com',
        'alt' = 'picture'
    );

    wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

    echo '<img src="' . $link . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
}
```

Setting `$args = ''` in the function means that the parameter is optional.  If nothing's passed in, your function will use the defaults you define instead.

So if you call `helloworld('link=www.facebook.com')` you'd see `<img src="www.facebook.com" alt="picture" />`.  If you called `helloworld('alt=link')` you'd see `<img src="www.google.com" alt="link" />`.  Remember, the function will use whatever you list in the `$defaults` array if you don't override it with something else.

The `extract()` function will pull out each element of the array and put it into its own variable.  You don't *need* to do this, though.  If you leave it out, you'd just referece `$args['link']` instead of `$link`.  It's really up to you.

Comment: Just FYI, it's bad form to downvote a post without an explanation ...